# Apply inner join between two tables result failed

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a Two tables. Names are **tbl_Module_Contact** and **tbl_Module_Contact_Details**.

Now,tbl_Module_Contact ----> Columns are ----> ContactID, CategoryID, TypeID, CustomerID, Status all **Numeric**

Now, second Table tbl_Module_Contact_Details----> Columns are -----> RecordID, ContactID, LanguageID, Keywords, Icon, LocationName, Logo here Ico, LocationName ,Logo and Keywords **String** typesand all others are **Numeric**

Now what i want is. Create a Query Using **INNER JOIN**. I want to fetch all the data from **tbl_Module_Contact_Details** where `status=1` and `keyword` ,`categoryID` and `LanguageID` that i have passed and also `Logo name` ends with `.jpg` or `.png` and at last Order by `LocationName`.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_using_joins.htm)

Comment: ok first tell me your DB is ready and you want to execute this query?

Comment: @SimplePlan ya it's ready just need to built a query

Comment: @user3414107 let me try this.

Comment: @user3414107 status=1 is coming from your `tbl_Module_Contact` right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `Open()` your `DB` and Execute the below query

```
Cursor mCursor = db
            .rawQuery(
                    "SELECT * FROM tbl_Module_Contact_Details INNER JOIN tbl_Module_Contact ON tbl_Module_Contact_Details.ContactID=tbl_Module_Contact.ContactID and tbl_Module_Contact_Details.LanguageID='"
                            + LanguageID
                            + "' and tbl_Module_Contact.CategoryID='"
                            + CategoryID
                            + "' and tbl_Module_Contact.Status=1 Where Keywords like '%"
                            + searchword
                            + "%' and (Logo like '%.jpg' OR Logo like '%.png') order by LocationName ",
                    null);

    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
```

Here in this Query you need to pass `LanguageID`,`CategoryID` and `searchword` .All the data coming into the `Cursor` fetch it and used it.

Try this `Query` and give me feedback on this

Comment: OMG! it's awesome. your query is right men. but wait one thing is problem here. i need to find data as alphabetical order but here it's not.

Comment: @user3414107 what do you mean data is not in alphabetical order?

Comment: i mean my data is not coming into alphabet order. i think it's may be my some data contains Location Name capital letters. so it might be a problem

Comment: ok i have solution for that add **COLLATE NOCASE** into your query after order by **LocationName**

Comment: @SP you are like _Father of SQLITE_. i mean it's work like a charm men. thank you so much.